# Extracting <span> element text

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been able to successfully get the tag that I want. However when I am looking at the websites code via inspect on my browser, I can see there is a data value. When I scrape the websites HTML code in, the data value isn't there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/ontario/ottawa")

if page.status_code == 200:
    print("Page downloaded")
else:
    print("Page download failed")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Locate current temperature
test = soup.find("span", {"class":"temp"})

print(test)
```

The result set that I am getting back is `<span class="temp"></span>`
Am I using the wrong function to return my results back? I have also tried using the `soup.select()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get anything back, because the values are dynamically rendered by `JS`. However, you can make a request to their API to get all the data.

```
import requests

data = requests.get("https://www.theweathernetwork.com/api/data/caon0512/cm/ci?ts=1652").json()
print(data['obs']['tc'])
```

This gets you current observable temperature in Ottawa in C: `11`.

To get more data:

```
import requests

data = requests.get("https://www.theweathernetwork.com/api/data/caon0512/cm/ci?ts=1652").json()

print(data['obs']['updatetime'])
sunrise = data['obs']['sunrise_time']
temp_c = data['obs']['tc']
wind, wind_unit = data['obs']['w'], data['obs']['wu']
humidity = data['obs']['h']
visibility, visibility_unit = data['obs']['v'], data['obs']['vu']
air_quality = data['obs']['aq_index']

print(f"Sunrise: {sunrise} | Current temp: {temp_c} C | Wind: {wind} {wind_unit}")
print(f"Humidity: {humidity}% | Visibility: {visibility} {visibility_unit}")
print(f"Air quality index: {air_quality}")
```

This gets you:

```
Sun Oct 18 1:15 PM
Sunrise: 7:23 AM | Current temp: 13 C | Wind: 17 km/h
Humidity: 47% | Visibility: 24 km
Air quality index: 2
```

Comment: This is useful but when I look through the json file I see there are repetitive attributes, such as ```metric_feelsLike``` if I try extracting this data set I get an error. Should I be returning that as a list and sorting through all the possible outcomes?